# System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations: load a wrong version which does not exist (Entity Framework 6, NOT core)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am trying to use code-first approach to configure a .net 4.5 project with libraries of

- System.Data.SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations

I have everything set up successfully in a POC sandbox and it works fine. Following exactly the same configuration in the production project, I have got error raised when using Add-Migration command.

It shows it needs Version=1.0.104.0 but the project is using 1.0.112.1. The corresponding dlls are in bin folder so they are supposed to be read correctly. Plus, I have checked every possible location and ensured all dll files are 1.0.112.1, including GAC and csproj. There should be no place using a wrong version of SQLite.EF6

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'
   at System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations.SQLiteMigrationSqlGenerator..ctor()
   at School.ExcelAddin.Data.SQLiteDB.Configuration..ctor() in C:\School.ExcelAddin.Data.SQLiteDB\Configuration.cs:line 16
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.GetMigrationsConfiguration(String migrationsConfigurationName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.ScaffoldInternal(String name, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, String migrationsConfigurationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.Scaffold.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.104.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself. **System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migration**s from nuget is using a different (older) version of **System.Data.SQLite.EF6** and **System.Data.SQLite** from nuget repository. When newing up a *SQLiteMigrationSqlGenerator* instance, it points to the older version of **System.Data.SQLite.EF6** (v1.0.104.0) which is conflicting the current loaded assembly (1.0.112.1).